# Issues when uploading data to Google Alerts

Tags: google-alerts

I am trying to upload a list of companies to Google Alerts, but getting this error:

```
CasperError: Errors encountered while filling form: Unable to find field element in form: FieldNotFound: setField: Invalid field ; only HTMLElement is supported
  /Users/sam/Documents/Work/google-alerts-export-import/phantomjs:/platform/casper.js:837 in fillForm
  /Users/sam/Documents/Work/google-alerts-export-import/phantomjs:/platform/casper.js:930 in fillSelectors
  /Users/sam/Documents/Work/google-alerts-export-import/phantomjs:/code/galerts.js:229
  /Users/sam/Documents/Work/google-alerts-export-import/phantomjs:/platform/casper.js:1637 in runStep
  /Users/sam/Documents/Work/google-alerts-export-import/phantomjs:/platform/casper.js:414 in checkStep
```

Here's the `sample.csv` file data:

```
Apple;At most once a week;Blogs;English;Argentina;All results;RSS feed
```

And I run it as:

```
casperjs galerts.js import --file=sample.csv --delete-others
```

Here's the Github for the program:

```
https://github.com/jra11/google-alerts-export-import
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens due to mismatch in versions of library, downgrade casper.